# Find working with regexp in same CWD but not from another directory

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression

I have a find command and I would like to issue it from an arbitrary directory with a `$directory` variable in place of the dot `.` for the current working directory.

What works is this

- Example 1

```
find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "test*"
```

That gives me some results.

Also this works

- Example 2

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^./[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$"
```

However, with a `$directory` it doesn't work. Mind that I removed the `./` at the beginning of the regex.

- Example 3

```
find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$"
```

Why is that so?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-regex` (not standard), like the standard `-path` matches on the full path of the files. Those paths start with the contents of `$directory` followed by the dirs and files found by `find`. So if `$directory` is `/some/dir`, `-regex` will match the regex against `/some/dir/file-discovered-by-find`, and will never match here as the first character is a `/`, not an alnum.

In the first case, your regexp started with `^./` (should have been `^\./` as `.` is a regexp operator, or just `\./` as `^` is implied in GNU `find`'s `-regex`) as `$directory` there was `.`.

You'd need to do something similar with `$directory`, bearing in mind that all regexp operators in `$directory` (`^$*()+[]?.\`...) would need to be escaped. But here you might as well do:

```
find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*/[[:alnum:]]+([-_][[:alnum:]]+)*-[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){0,3}'
```

(I've also replaced `.` with `\.` as I suspect you want to match a literal `.` and not just any character, and removed the `?` which was not necessary here).

That is, have your pattern (which here is guaranteed not to encompass a `/`) match after any `/` (and up to the end of the file path as `$` is also implied) rather than after something that matches `$directory`.

With `zsh -o extendglob`, you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob
w=[0-9a-zA-Z] d=[0-9]
print -rC1 -- $directory/$~w##([-_]$~w##)#-$~d(#c1,3)(.$~d(#c1,3))(#c0,3)(#q/)
```

Which has several advantages over the GNU `find` one:

- would work even on non-GNU systems (removes the dependency to GNU `find`)
- works even if `$directory` starts with `-`
- gives you a sorted list
- in `zsh`, what `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches is not random and doesn't vary with the locales like in `find` and matches the characters I suppose you want matched and only them. In `find`, you'd need `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]` to get the equivalent.
- it works even if `$directory` is a symlink to a directory (you can add the `-H` option to `find` for that though).
- it works even if the file paths (in this case the contents of `$directory`) contains sequence of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale (`find`'s `-regex`'s `.*` could not match on those as `.` only matches valid characters).
- instead of printing that list, you can use it directly (as arguments to a command, to loop over it, etc.)
- you can also use things like `(<0-255>~????*)` to match decimal numbers from 0 to 255 made of no more than 3 digits or `(<0-255>~0?*)` for those numbers without leading 0, `zsh` globs being one of the very few pattern matching APIs that support matching ranges of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your solution ! I learned alot and will try your solution! But I also changed my regex like this `"^${directory}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){,3}\$"` which now works with the `find` command but is weird because why would I specify the directory as second argument just to only be able to get results by prepending the `$directory` a **second time** to the regex? However. You gave the explanation why this is so. Thanks

Comment: @vonspotz, but like I said, you'd need to escape regexp operators in `$directory` first. For instance, if `$directory` is `[1] dir`, that won't work. Also as I said, the `^`, `$` are superflous, so is `?`. `.` should be escaped if you want it to match a literal `.` and `[a-z]` would match a lot more characters than you might thing it does.

Comment: Yes I saw my mistake that I didn't escape the dot. But btw: What if I don't use zsh? And what's the default for `set -o extendedglob` so I can set it back to the default after the search?

Comment: `extendedglob` is off by default in `zsh`, but you likely want it on all the time. It's off by default for backward compatibility so that `~`, `^` and `#` are not treated specially, but those characters should in general be quoted if you want them to be literal as they have other special meanings in zsh and most shells.